# Effect of redirection on ranking

Tags: seo

I am working as an SEO on my client's domain. I am new to SEO. I need to change the extension of the default page and many other pages from `.asp` to `.html`. The website is in the top 10 for many keywords and I don't want to lose my ranking.

Should I use a 301 redirect? Does redirection affect the ranking? If yes, then what percent and what are the other factors to consider while redirecting?

Answer (score 1):

Using 301 redirects to change the URL of many pages within your site does not usually cause ranking drops.   I have done so on large sites without hurting my rankings. You have to make sure that:

- You use 301 permanent redirects, not 302 temporary redirects
- You don't redirect to error pages
- Your redirects work with one hop (no redirect to a redirect to a page)
- No infinite redirects

In short, do lots of testing before you roll it out.

[Google has been ambiguous about whether redirects have an effect on PageRank](http://www.seroundtable.com/redirects-links-pagerank-16419.html).  Matt Cutts used to say that a redirect cost 10% of PR.  He recently corrected himself and says that it doesn't cost PR at all.   Since redirects don't seem to cause ranking drops, their technical impact on PR is irrelevant for practical purposes.